# If statement at postgis

Tags: postgis

I have two shapefiles, one with points and one with polygons.

I have written a query for checking whether the point is inside a polygon and if it is inside, assign a value.

However, I want to assign the value 0 if the point is not inside the polygon.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT polygon.gid, time, avg(value) 
FROM   polygon,geo
WHERE  ST_Contains(polygon.geom,geo.geom)
GROUP  BY polygon.gid,time
```

I have multiple values for each point at different times.

Comment: Do you have shapefiles (file-based binary data, partially modeled using dBaseIII+) or do you have ***tables*** loaded from shapefiles? Once loaded into the database they are NOT shapefiles. Please consider naming your tables usefully (e.g., "my_polygons" and "my_points"), and make use of the JOIN keyword in your queries to improve clarity (using JOIN is also the answer to your question, since you need a LEFT OUTER JOIN to find unmatched rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the hint of Vince the answer is:

```
SELECT polygon.gid, time, avg(value) 
FROM polygon 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  geo
    ON ST_Contains(polygon.geom,geo.geom)
GROUP BY polygon.gid,time
```